# How to plot weights attached to 3 different filters?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using one convolution layer and one fully connected layer in CNN. where as there are two output nodes. I'm using one input channel and 3 filter channel in the convolutional layer(1D convolution). When I store final weight matrix of fully connected layer it has shape (36,2). Whereas a single input has 12 features. Now I want to plot filter weights attached to 1st channel, second channel and third channel separately.  If I plot first 12 weights Does it mean they correspond to the 1 class of first channel?

```
`
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv1d(input, filter):
    return tf.nn.conv1d(input, filter, stride=1, padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FLAGS.image_width])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

input = tf.reshape(x, [-1, FLAGS.image_width, FLAGS.input_channel])
filter = weight_variable([FLAGS.filter_width,  FLAGS.input_channel, 
FLAGS.filter_channel])

conv_out = tf.nn.tanh(conv1d(input, filter))



#Fully_Connected_layer
dim = conv_out.get_shape().as_list()

conv_re = tf.reshape(conv_out, (-1, dim[1]*dim[2]))
W_fc = weight_variable([dim[1]*dim[2], 2])
logits = tf.matmul(conv_re, W_fc)
y_prime = tf.nn.softmax(logits)


#Cross_entropy:
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, 
labels= y_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.rLearn).minimize(loss)


#Check_predictions:
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_prime, axis=1),tf.argmax(y_, 
axis=1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))`




`W = W.eval()  #shape (36,2)
W1 = W[0:12,0]
W2 = W[12:24,0]
W3 = W[24:36,0]`
```

Comment: Is there anything that is not clear in my Question?

Comment: Yes, can you provide a bit more information about the structure of your model? For example, `kernel_size` of the Conv1D layer. Also, does there happen to be a `Flatten` layer between the Conv1D layer and the Dense layer? It would be useful to include the code used to create the model, or the output of `model.summary()`.

Comment: Kernal size is 2 with a stride of 1. Convolution is performed using 3 output channel and input channel is is 1. After convolution layer I used fully connected layer having 2 output nodes.